# How to delete the each socket client when disconnecting the socket

Tags: node.js

Is not work when calling the
Below code

- socket.on(“disconnect”,function ()
- { delete socket.id; });

Comment: Please add some more details and code to your question. Nobody will be able to help you with the given information :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.